# How do I perform a spatial query on this area?

Tags: qgis, spatial-query

I am in the process of trying to perform spatial analysis bike on bicycle trip data publicly found on Citibike's website. I want to extract data for each square in the rectangle (the boundary-lines shapefile that encompasses the bike stations. In the **box** group, I have a lines layer that defines the grid of the rectangle. What I wish to do is extract data of each square in this rectangle, ex. find the middle point, find the number of stations in each square and more. How would one attempt do this? Do I have to make use of raster data instead?[image: qgis citibike tripdata]

Comment: Welcome to [GIS.SE]! Please take the [tour] to get familiar with the best practices on this board, e.g. our standards towards a good question and how to reward answers. While I personally thought your question is possible to answer (and I did so), note that 'close votes' have been raised due to lack of focus, clarity and details!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You seem to work with PostGIS, so I assume you are fine with an SQL solution.*

Create grid cells as *Polygons* with unique `ids` and aggregate over those; use [`ST_Polygonize`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Polygonize.html) to get the maximum amount of *Polygons* possible from a set of *LineStrings*, without overlapping areas (which simply translates to 'create those grid cells' in this case):

```
SELECT dmp.path[1] AS id,
       dmp.geom
FROM   (
  SELECT ST_Polygonize(geom) AS geom
  FROM   lines
) AS polygonized
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
       ST_Dump(geom) AS dmp
;
```

If your lines are not noded correctly (split at each intersection), `ST_Polygonize` will produce unwanted (or no) results; use [`ST_Node`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Node.html) here:

```
SELECT dmp.path[1] AS id,
       dmp.geom
FROM   (
  SELECT ST_Polygonize(geom) AS geom
  FROM   (
    SELECT ST_Node(St_Collect(geom)) AS geom
    FROM   lines
  ) AS noded
) AS polygonized
CROSS JOIN LATERAL
       ST_Dump(geom) AS dmp
;
```

Use this with a `UNION ALL` of the `ST_ExteriorRing` of the `boundary-layer` as a new innermost subquery if you need to add the outer shell of your grid (when those lines are not present in your `lines` layer...I cannot say for sure from your picture).

---

With these cells you can go and aggregate whatever you need from those other tables:

```
WITH
  grid AS (
    <any_of_the_above>
  )

SELECT g.id,
       COUNT(s.*) AS number_of_stations_in_cell
FROM   grid AS g
JOIN   stations AS s
  ON   g.geom && s.geom
GROUP BY
       g.id
;
```

(note the use of the [`&&`](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_overlaps.html) bbox intersection operator; this works since we compare a regular (planar) grid with points. For other geometries `ST_Intersects` or similar may be needed!)

or extract the centroids

```
WITH
  grid AS (
    <any_of_the_above>
  )

SELECT id,
       ST_Centroid(geom) AS geom
FROM   grid
;
```

(which is in fact a bit silly as you can create them directly in the grid queries).

---

I would suggest you create a table (or [*Materialized View*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rules-materializedviews.html)) with those grid cells rather than generating them on-the-fly; while technically it likely won't matter much to have an index on those cells (for this particular task; however, an index on any joined layer is mandatory for performance!), a consistent `id` order is not guaranteed when recreating them per call. And of course it adds overall ease of use for whatever future tasks.

Comment: If you *can* work with PostGIS integration in QGIS, and this does help you, please add [tag:postgis] to your tags. Note that a similar approach, with slightly different syntax, is possible vie QGIS *Virtual Layers* (using the SQLite dialect).

Comment: Thanks for this. This is the output in the end https://imgur.com/JSPO1K4 and I don't think the numbers are correct. Unfortunately I may have to change my methodology. I was thinking of looping 9 times, creating a box polygon for each iteration, with each box having its own coordinates. Then I would apply spatial queries on these boxes instead rather than lines as I tried to do it.

Comment: There seem to be only 6 boxes in the output? If so, the cells are not created correctly. Can you share those grid geometries? This approach *does* creates Polygons first to aggregate over, iteration is quite unnecessary.

Comment: This is the query I used from your suggestions which resulted in the 6 boxes output, which is wrong because I need 9 boxes in total.
`WITH
  grid AS (
 SELECT dmp.path[1] AS id,
     dmp.geom
 FROM   (
   SELECT ST_Polygonize(the_geom) AS geom
   FROM   citibike.lines
 ) AS polygonized
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     ST_Dump(geom) AS dmp
  )

SELECT g.id,
       COUNT(s.*) AS number_of_stations_in_cell
FROM   grid AS g
JOIN   citibike.stationslayer AS s
  ON   g.geom && s.geom
GROUP BY
       g.id;`

Also, this is my database structure. https://imgur.com/a/pWHtmcW

Comment: Ok! Managed to do get a working result. From the QGIS toolbox I used 'Create polygons graticule'. I saved it to PostGIS and ran the query you created and it worked with 9 boxes! Thanks so much @ThingumaBob